# How to stop Google Docs from pasting titles instead of links

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs's functionality changed within the past month, such that now for many different websites, it will automatically replace the link with the title of the website.

For example, if I copy `https://www.dhs.gov/science-and-technology/commercialized-technologies` and paste it into a Google Doc, it will paste [`Commercialized Technologies | Homeland Security (dhs.gov)`](https://www.dhs.gov/science-and-technology/commercialized-technologies).

**How do I stop this functionality?**

I know I can undo it by editing the link and the text itself, but I'd like it to just paste the URL in the first place, rather than using the title.

(This is important to me because I'm creating a Google Doc report that will be pasted into a form that doesn't support rich text - thus, all of my links need to be the actual URL or the person who gets the form won't be able to see the URL.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste without formatting)

Sample result screenshot:

> [image: Google Docs Sample]

Comment: Looks like it doesn't quite paste as a *link* for me, I still have to select it and hit `Ctrl + K`, but this is good enough!